# Js/React обучение пользователя

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Немного нестандартный вопрос. Я делаю один проект-игру. В целом интерфейс интуитивно понятен, но люди, которые не знакомы с тематикой игры (майнинг), часто путаются и не знают, куда клика.

Поэтому появилась необходимость сделать обучение. Как знаете, в играх выделены области, куда смотрить, их описание, и показано куда кликать. Есть у кого ссылка на реализацию сие чуда?

Вполне понятно, что можно создать отдельный компонент, обернуть в него всё остальное. И в нём сделать состояние - текущий шаг обучения. И показывать пользовтелю подстказки, а также выделять те области экрана, куда нужно нажать.

Но, я думаю, может есть какая-нибудь готовая, более простая реализация. Или у вас есть идеи, как это сделать проще?

Спасибо)

Comment: OK GOOGLE: react interactive tour :)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Вот как оно называется) А я искал guide, instruction и тд)